# am trying to make form using foreign, can i have some suggest using django

Tags: django

```
class DemoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=SimpleDemo
        fields=['First_name','Last_name']

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Post
        fields = ['Enter_Message',]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're talking about forms and "foreign" but not showing your models or what you mean by "form using foreign". Please clarify what you're trying to achieve, maybe show your view code and model code if that helps to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) are straight forward for your application.

You declare a foreign key field just the same as every other field.